# Unit testing Doctrine: can't mock repository method

Tags: php, testing, doctrine-orm, doctrine, phpunit

I'm trying to mock a Doctrine repository and the entityManager, but PHPUnit keeps telling me that:

> 1) CommonUserTest::testGetUserById Trying to configure method "findBy"
>   which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been
>   specified, is final, or is static

Here's the snippet:

```php
<?php
use \Domain\User as User;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CommonUserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{    
    public function testGetUserById()
    {
        // mock the repository so it returns the mock of the user (just a random string)
        $repositoryMock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(EntityRepository::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $repositoryMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('findBy')
            ->willReturn('asdasd');

        // mock the EntityManager to return the mock of the repository
        $entityManager = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(EntityManager::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $entityManager->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->willReturn($repositoryMock);

        // test the user method
        $userRequest = new User($entityManager);
        $this->assertEquals('asdasd', $userRequest->getUserById(1));
    }
}
```

Any help? I tried a few variations of this code but can't get passed this specific error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Which version of PHPUnit are you using?

anyway, check this possible solution:

```
$repositoryMock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(EntityRepository::class)
            ->setMethods(['findBy'])
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks (gràcies)! This lead me to the answer, I applied your change and did the same with the `$entityManager` mock.